# Cassandra GUI tool -- Helenos does not return value when I query

Tags: cassandra

I have installed the Helenos successfully according to https://github.com/tomekkup/helenos.
[image]

But when I use cql to query, I got nothing. 
Anyone can help me ? thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know anything about Helenos, but considering you are interested in a Cassandra GUI tool you should check out [DevCenter](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/introducing-datastax-devcenter). It has a Win and Mac version and you should be able to run CQL queries. Next versions will bring some more interesting features.